# Setting a date field to specific date

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have a table that has 2 date fields that I need to modify.

- If one of the fields <= jan 1 2017 then set it to jan 1 2017
- If the other field is >= Dec 31 2017 then set it to Dec 31 2017

I've tried the following

```
Update table set field1 = date '01-jan-2017' where field1 <= '01-jan-2017'
```

This is for oracle sql server

Comment: Your table has 2 date _columns_.

Comment: _"where field1 <= '01-jan-2017'"_   Assuming "field1" is - as it should be - a DATE data type, then you are comparing it to a _string_, not a data.  This forces an internal TO_DATE() operation, using the controlling setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  Depending on that setting, this may or may not work. Far better to be explicit:  where field1 <= to_date('01-jan-2017','dd-mon-yyyy')

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `CASE`:

```
update table set
  field1 = case when one_of_the_fields <= date '2017-01-01' then date '2017-01-01'
                when other_field >= date '2017-12-31' then date '2017-12-31'
                else field1
           end;
```